# Is enum a macro or integer variable in C++?

Tags: c++

Is an `enum` a macro or a variable in C++? I am confused about macros in C++. What is the definition of macro in C++?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/macros-c-cpp?view=vs-2019

Comment: No, macros are only created using `#define`. (There are also some built-in macros, that can be detected with `#ifdef` and others. Also some command-line parameters of you compiler can create macros.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Enum

In c++ there are two kinds of `enum`:

1. enum classes
2. plain enums

This is how to declare them:

```cpp
enum Day { sunday, monday, tuesday };  // plain enum
enum class Color { red, green, blue }; // enum class
```

What is the difference?

`enums` - The enumerator names `{ sunday, monday, tuesday }` are in the same scope as the enum and their values implicitly convert to integers and other types.

`enum class` - enumerator names `{ red, green, blue }` are local to the enum and their values do not implicitly convert to other types (like another `enum` or `int`)

It is generally accepted that `enum class` is preferred to plain `enum` because it is part of the c++ type system, they don't convert implicitly to `int`, they don't pollute the namespace, and they can be forward-declared. Using `enum class` can protect you from some bugs that can arise form plain `enum`.

### Macro

A macro is a totally different thing. Macros are used by the preprocessor, which is a program that process the source code **before** compilation. Macros are a piece of code in a program which is given some name. Whenever this name is encountered by the compiler the compiler replaces the name with the actual piece of code. The `#define` directive is used to define a macro. For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream> 
  
// macro definition 
#define LIMIT 5 

int main() 
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < LIMIT; ++i)
    { 
        std::cout << i << "\n"; 
    }  
}
```

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

A macro can also act like a function

```cpp
#include <iostream> 
  
// macro with parameter 
#define AREA(l, b) ((l) * (b)) 

int main() 
{ 
    int a = 10, b = 5, area; 
  
    area = AREA(a, b); 
  
    std::cout << "Area of rectangle is: " << area; 
}
```

```
Area of rectangle is: 50
```

The macro is replaced by the preprocessor so there is no function call. This can make code run faster, however, in c++ functions can be inlined by the compiler which is preferred over using macros. Macros can be problematic if you don't define and use them carefully.